# The copied CSS selector from the browser returns a different result using BeautifulSoup4 in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Usually when I want to scrape a particular text from a website, I right click the text and select inspect. Then in the HTML code, I look for the text I am interested in and **`right-click -> 'copy' -> 'copy selector'`**.

Then I paste that string of text I just copied within soup.select('enter copied text here') and save it to a variable. I can then perform text stripping functions to get the key text I need.

Now for the situation I am working with, I want to get the total number of cars shown on this webpage in the header `h1: cars.com/cars/used/.`

This is my code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

url = "https://www.cars.com/used"
headers = {'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/101.0.4951.41 Safari/537.36'}

res = requests.get(url,headers = headers)
res.raise_for_status()

soup = bs(res.text, 'html.parser')

total_cars_element = soup.select('body > div.listing > div.container.listing-container.has-header-sticky > div.row.flex-nowrap.no-gutters > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(1) > div')

print(total_cars)
# the above prints an empty list.
```

I really just want to know why this is not working. I understand there are other work arounds as I have mentioned in the code above. But I really want to stick with the soup.select method.

Any insights are much appreciated!
Thanks!

Comment: Hey! could you add the status code that it shows you? When I try your code I see 403, which means that access to the requested resource is forbidden. The server understood the request, but will not fulfill it.
If this is the case then you may need to try different headers (or the website simply cannot be accessed)

Comment: @MilindSharma - I get status 200, which I believe is the OK status. I think you might have to change headers for your machine? I am not sure, I am learning all this stuff by myself.

Comment: The site throws a captch occasionally so you might be getting 200 but not the HTML you think you're getting.

Comment: interesting....I guess I need to find alternatives....

Comment: what is the expected result should be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue stems from the fact that the HTML fetched via Python is not the same as the one that gets generated in your browser. Try printing `soup` and see for yourself.

One particular tag, which is part of your query, is troublesome. In the browser, it looks like this:

```html
<div class="container listing-container has-header-sticky">
```

but your Python code sees this instead:

```html
<div class="container listing-container">
```

Change your selector to:

```
body > div.listing > div.container.listing-container > div.row.flex-nowrap.no-gutters > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(1) > div
```

and you'll get the expected result.

---

This behaviour is considered normal since the page you're trying to scrape is *dynamic*. That means that JavaScript adds or removes certain parts of the original HTML page *after* the page loads.

If you want to scrape a dynamic web page using Python, you'll need something more than just Beautiful Soup. See https://scrapingant.com/blog/scrape-dynamic-website-with-python for more info on that subject.

Comment: Wow Thank you so much! That makes perfect sense. And thank you for providing me with the link on how to scrape dynamic website.

Answer (score 1):

*with [@Janez Kuhar](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72423576/4539709) nice Answer, You could also use*

```
total_cars_element = soup.select('h1.title')
print(total_cars_element[0].text)
```

more about [CSS Select](https://facelessuser.github.io/soupsieve/)